# Find an example showing that the conditional 'else' if different from writing the conditional 'if not'

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am doing my Python homework on the chapter of conditionals and one of the problems says:

> ```
> if condition_1:
>     instructions_1
> else:
>     instructions_2
> instruction_n
> ```
>
> can be replaced by
>
> ```
> if condition_1:
>     instructions_1
> if not condition_1:
>     instructions_2
> instruction_n
> ```

And I need to find an example where these two codes aren't equivalent.

I don't believe I'm supposed to use anything very complicated (so far we've learned only about functions, variables, booleans and conditionals). What would be a situation that would solve this problem?

Comment: if `instructions_1` changed the value of `condition_1` to `False` then the second example would behave differently, because `condition_1` is evaluated twice in two separate `if` blocks, whereas in the first example it is only evaluated once

Comment: @Anentropic - that would be a good answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I want to help, but I'm not about to do your homework for you. Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). If you want more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Any time you change the data involved in the condition in reaction to its True result, following this with another if on the reverse of that condition could give a different result than an else block.

for example:

Using if-else:

```
if a > b:             # when a=7 and b=4
   a = a - b          # only this is executed: a = 7-4 = 3
else:
   a = b - a
```

This if/else will place the absolute value of the difference between `a` and `b` in `a`.

Using two ifs with the reversed condition:

```
if a > b:             # when a=7 and b=4
   a = a - b          # this will be executed: a = 7-4 = 3
if not a > b:         # now not 3 > 4 is also True
   a = b - a          # this will be executed: a = 4-3 = 1
```

This however, will not work when `b` is larger than half of `a` because the new value of `a` will be compared again and `not a > b` will also be True (which would not happen when the second calculation is in the else block)

Re-testing an inverse condition, apart from being inefficient, is error prone.  Even if you don't change the condition values in reaction to the True result, you're setting a trap for someone (even yourself) that would need to change the code later and might not think to look farther down the code for this particular pattern.

One way to avoid this while still using two ifs (lets say you have some code to execute systematically between the two ifs) would be to use a boolean variable:

```
positiveDiff = a > b
if positiveDiff:
    a = a - b
...
if not positiveDiff:
    a = b - a
```

This way, the result of the `a > b` comparison is preserved and reusable independently of any changes made to the variables.

Comment: Understood! thanks very much for the clear explanation. : )
It makes absolute sense the way you explained it

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0

def f():
    global x
    x += 1
    return x == 1

if f():
    print("yes")

if not f():
    print("yes")
```

In the above example f mutates the global variable x every time it's called.